# What causes motor laterality/ side dominance?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology, neuroplasticity

I would like to understand what leads up to motor laterality, or side dominance of motor skills.
I made this assumption that it depends on neuroplasticity and the side in which one first learns the motor skill; whereas the more you practice, the more you strengthen that side. I appreciate your time and patience. Thank you; can't wait to discuss.

Comment: I think this question is overly broad in scope. There is abundant literature on the various causes of handedness: genetic, epigenetic and environmental. The following might serve as an introduction: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-37423-8.

Comment: I found this article on forced right-handedness; can I get your opinion on if it supports my assumption, @Adhish? Thank you for your help! https://blog.cognifit.com/ambidextrous-brain/

Comment: The available evidence (and the article you shared) suggest that training does play a role. So your assumption is correct to an extent. But inherited factors are important too.

Comment: Ah, Thank you! Just one more question, if you don't mind me asking: What "category" of factors would training/practice fall under? Physical factors? My apologies; I'm very new to this field. Thank you for your patience, @Adhish.