# What type of factor is practice of motor skills?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology, neuroplasticity

I recently asked a question about the cause of motor laterality: [What causes motor laterality/ side dominance?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/what-causes-motor-laterality-side-dominance)

I understand that there can be genetic factors, epigenetic factors, or environmental factors. *But in terms of continuous practice of motor skills, what type of factor will that be?* Physical factors? Thank you!

Comment: Hopefully someone will post an answer to your linked question as well!

Comment: @uhoh Hope so! So far I've only been conversing in the comments, as you've probably seen.  •-•