# What are kinesiological factors?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neurology, bio-mechanics

I am in search of a term that describes movement, or practice of motor skills, as a factor of laterality. Would "kinesiological" be appropriate? I'll leave my two previous questions down below; hopefully it can shed more light. Thank you so much!

[What type of factor is practice of motor skills?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95369/what-type-of-factor-is-practice-of-motor-skills)

[What causes motor laterality/ side dominance?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/what-causes-motor-laterality-side-dominance)

Comment: There is no magic dictionary of "factors" that biologists use and that those writing about Biology must draw from. It seems you want to describe "practice", so use that word, "practice".

Comment: Hi @BryanKrause! Thanks for the reply; I'm writing a script for a "scicomm" video and wanted to say something to this effect: "Keep in mind, there are genetic, environmental, physical factors, et cetera, but I'll be focusing on the _________."

Comment: If you presumably plan to refer to the literature then you can use the language used in the relevant texts.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your time and patience, @BryanKrause .